# Reading wrong characters from XML code

Tags: php

I have a PHP program that reads MySql database table and prints that table in XML format. Now I want to read that PHP file (with XML code) to my C# application with this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/baza.php");

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader input = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                //MessageBox.Show(input.ReadLine());
                DataSet dsTest = new DataSet();
                dsTest.ReadXml(input);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTest;
```

But I got an exception because input.ReadLine() returns XML string but with some wrong characters (for example < replaces with &lt ; or " replaces with &quot ;).
I know I could just use string.replace but that's not the best solution for me.
This is what I see when I run PHP code in browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MessageXML><row1><ID> 1 </ID><Ime> Pera </Ime><Prezime> Zdera </Prezime></row></MessageXML>
```

And this is what I am getting in MessageBox:

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;MessageXML&gt;&lt;row1&gt;&lt;ID&gt; 1 &lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Ime&gt; Pera &lt;/Ime&gt;&lt;Prezime&gt; Zdera &lt;/Prezime&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/MessageXML&gt;
```

EDIT:
PHP code:

```
<?php

$dbhost = '###';
$dbuser = '###';
$dbpass = '###';
$dbname = '###';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM nalog";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo htmlentities("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
echo htmlentities("<MessageXML>");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 echo htmlentities("<row1>"."<ID> {$row['id']} </ID>"."<Ime> {$row['ime']} </Ime>"."<Prezime> {$row['prezime']} </Prezime>"."</row>");
} 
echo htmlentities('</MessageXML>');
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: So you don't have XML. You have HTML escaped XML. This is a PHP question, and you should provide the code that generates the XML, because this is what's broken.

Comment: Added it. htmlentities is probably causing the problem, but still not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trial this, and when you review by the browser press CTRL+U to see the source page

```
<?php

$dbhost = '###';
$dbuser = '###';
$dbpass = '###';
$dbname = '###';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM nalog";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>;
echo "<MessageXML>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 echo "<row1>"."<ID> {$row['id']} </ID>"."<Ime> {$row['ime']} </Ime>"."<Prezime> {$row['prezime']} </Prezime>"."</row>";
} 
echo '</MessageXML>';
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: I thought input is only reading text that's visible to me (without entering source). Thanks for the answer